# Getting "No keyword with name 'Launch Application' found." while trying to execute whitelibrary code in robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework, robotframwork-whitelibrary

I have installed **python** :

[image]

Then my **pip list** are :

[image]

I have installed white library and try to execute a script with 1 line with Launch Application keyword.

**Code:**

[image]

But when I try to execute the script I'm getting "No keyword with name 'Launch Application' found." error message.

In terminal I'm getting this:
[image]

What can I do for this?

Any suggestion.

Comment: https://github.com/Omenia/robotframework-whitelibrary#deprecation-notice - Also, whitelibrary itself (not just the RF bindings) is not being maintained anymore.

Comment: If you really really need to use whitelibrary - downgrade your python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WhiteLibrary is using `getargspec` from `inspect` module which is no longer present in Python 3.11. As solution you could downgrade python version to 3.10.

Comment: I downgraded python version and white library is working fine. Thanks for your suggestions.